# Highlighting TGrid row in code

Tags: c++, c++builder, firemonkey, c++builder-xe7, tgrid

I have a custom `TGrid` control which I am trying to make it so when the mouse hovers over a row, that row is highlighted.  Rows are automatically highlighted if I used the arrow keys to navigate the grid.  However, I am not sure how to replicate this effect for navigation with the mouse.

Currently, I have a MouseMove function which can detect which row of the grid the mouse is hovering over.

```
void __fastcall TFmSearchBar::GridMouseMove(TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, float X, float Y)
{
    int rowSelected = FGrid->RowByPoint(X, Y);

    if(rowSelected >= FGrid->RowCount)
        rowSelected = FGrid->RowCount - 1;

    if(rowSelected != -1)
    {
        FGrid->SelectRow(rowSelected);
    }
}
```

I originally thought using the `SelectRow` function would achieve the desired effect, however nothing happens when that method is used.  Additionally I have tried using

`FGrid->SelectCell(0, rowSelected);`

which did not work either.

I have verified that I am getting the right row from the function by setting a row's text to bold when the mouse hovers over it using

`FGrid->RowObjects[rowSelected]->SetBold();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must enable following options for TGrid component:

1) RowSelect = True
2) AlwaysShowSelection = True

Tested with Delphi XE8 -- works fine. My code:

```
procedure TForm1.Grid1MouseMove(Sender: TObject; Shift: TShiftState; X, Y: Single);
begin
  Grid1.SelectRow(Grid1.RowByPoint(X, Y));
end;
```

if you want, i could provide you DFM file either.